# exchange server show error message in error page

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server

How to can show exception message in custom error page for my exchange server?

I define and setup on custom error page that showed in error time to exchange users, but i will show exception message and stack trace of last exception into custom error page.

I user the following code but is null:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
Response.Write("Error");
```

when if is true i hope to show exception message and exception stack trace that raised in exchange application.

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
routeData.Values.Add("model", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, errorController, errorAction));

Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
IController controller = new Controllers.HomeController();
controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
Response.End();
```

With this code, you can open your custom error page with last server error.

Your Error Action should look like this;

```
public ActionResult Error(HandleErrorInfo model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Exchange server is web application and it is not  mvc project,please tell me correct code in asp web form, i cant understand mvc code for this problem